# Getting rid of dynamic allocation in C++20 coroutines

Tags: c++, c++20, dynamic-memory-allocation, raii, c++-coroutine

According to this [open-std discussion](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0981r0.html) the compiler is allowed to optimize out dynamic allocation of coroutines that are created and destroyed within a stack activation frame which makes sense to me. However, I cannot see this optimization happening with current compilers, at least not with gcc and msvc. I would asume that you would just need to destroy the coroutine handle on scoped exit? Here's my naive implementation:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIADMAKykAA6oCoRODB7evv6p6ZkCIWGRLDFxSbaY9o4CQgRMxAQ5Pn5c1bVZDU0EJRHRsXoKjc2teR0jvf1lFRIAlLaoXsTI7Bzm8aHI3lgA1Cbxbsgj%2BKiH2CYaAIKb27uYB0doxMuOYRdXt2ZbDDte%2B0ObicI2ImFYnxuX1BXgce2UrxYeCUhysUJuMLhHleXnejxAexSXiitDwyD2pxAKBIb1CmAA%2BghDOh6ECEagkSj4tgDgB2NHXPZCvZeDJGQmI5EMggATxSj0OABE9lT2ZzMKivl9hXsAH7Y2lhCDzPkCnU6rCg1Ay42am46ky8xVap1224YgjEWEEeGSpSm7XCpi41B7YCYAj0sEEFYMemoKLaTAOY17AC0Fz2BtxdNNe2jsbz2bxVKoiPpKT9mAgACoCAhkSbHc74lZXfagyG9qFMmJ6QpRfKGOhUwxUJhVGsUj6M9yKQR0FSBwoh%2Bh6WEAG6xPMF4gMAOu1vNwNC4NEPY0Zi0fuD1yj8eTzDT9OZykgZer%2BliADuTBlCh3CNC0dNsW1Ak89jPUMmF/Qh6U9QwFH4YgWFTWceTfD9XC/Whf3/QCYz3A8wOPDtTy7Xc4w3VA8BHE10L2ajaLzN80FxJ43CBA4zDMAAJGpaFDAB1EhaHQMAwHMMwOK4t9XFoVE%2BWdMjIK7LwGCZYd6DXCcpzqBg0MzJj0GIl0SPRa4oL2F5UHpdBUEMudi1zECtRUtAoyAoi3VI90/NCH0WCYUJU1clTnLCPYWBlGynmVGy7Ic%2BYfJU1i3hko4KTwAAvTBUCoCBopspsjlkhcqXkt0dSKmkADowQHNhbSPKEnQ4RZaE4RJeD8DgtFIVBOE4yxrApZZVgVH4eFIAhNHaxYAGsQESDR9E4SQermgbOF4BQQFW2a%2Bva0g4FgGBEGpFgUjoWJyEoNArpuuJgC4HjSCwDcyUwAA1PBMG/AB5IdOGmmhaAIWI9ogKItqiUImhlEHeDh5hiBlAHE2TQ7poethBABhhaERo73swIKjHEEn8DBBw8C3PaSYnZNcXWfqApqLbSSiYgEY8LAts9PAWCRxYqAMYAFF%2B/6gcYJGZEEEQxHYKR5fkJQ1C23QOgMIwUGsax9DwKI9sgRZUGnLIGbTU4lVMEbLDMDR0wBgC0yEsRaF2mosayFxh3GdpAmHGZBjiDo0gyfSA70COigYEPyiGSZvdp%2BpRhaTw2mGFP9J6ZoE7mSZ0%2BjovpjpWYk8WBRxrWBY1o4brSF6/rBo4PZVAADgANjTLvJDDZByVe2rpIgXBCBIbj4i4eZeEOrR5kWBBwSwOJjVIJaVvrjbSGFrfm94Vvdv2ma5sWU6LreIkCDuiAHuu%2BhiHCVh1k7nu%2B4HoezBH3hMHwIhiC0T0PwBWohxAqxAWrFQ6gSZa1IN%2BHmKQRb10bgfbaHAAa4mvnsfK7du6937sAQeexh6jw8I9R%2BU8Z5zzPkvFeQx16dQ4DvPeq00FH1sCfee80N7LVWkw%2BIm0SYcO4YveuZghEtx2qfI6YitzEAyM4SQQA%3D%3D)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <coroutine>
#include <iostream>

struct Promise;

struct Coroutine : public std::coroutine_handle<Promise> {
    using promise_type = ::Promise;

    ~Coroutine() {
        destroy();
    }
};

struct Promise {
    auto get_return_object() -> Coroutine { return { Coroutine::from_promise(*this) };}
    auto initial_suspend() noexcept -> std::suspend_never { return {};}
    auto final_suspend() noexcept -> std::suspend_always { return {};}
    auto await_transform() -> std::suspend_always { return {};}
    auto return_void() -> void { std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl; }
    auto unhandled_exception() -> void {}
};

auto coro_do() -> Coroutine {

    co_return ;
}


int main() {
    Coroutine mycoro = coro_do();

    std::cout << sizeof(mycoro) << std::endl;
    mycoro.resume();
}
```

Is there more to it that I need to specify to get the promised optimization or are compilers just not quite there yet?

On another note afforementioned source explains the following:

> Coroutine escaping its caller: an operation within the caller of the
> coroutine that could make the address of the object of coroutine type
> visible outside the caller, excluding such cases where the compiler
> can prove that such escaping does not occur. For example: storing the
> address of the object of coroutine type into a global or through an
> externally-supplied pointer, or calling a member function on the
> object of coroutine type whose body is not available for examination
> (or is not examined due to optimizer limitations).

How exactly do I need to understand this? Does this mean for my case as long as the `Coroutine` object is kept in scope the heap alloction elision is possible? Or does this refer to the `coroutine_handle` type? Later would not make sense in imho because the handle can be non-owning and this would disallow this optimization for cases where you pass the handle around to run on different threads even though there is no harm in having the coroutine frame rest peacefully on the callers stack.

Related discussion: https://github.com/GorNishanov/coroutines-ts/issues/37

Comment: AFAIK clang seems to do the best job in coroutines.

Comment: the optimizations isnt "promised" but merely "allowed". I know its a nitpick on wording, but optimizations are never guaranteed. Even if the compiler is allowed and knows how to it does not necessarily apply it always.

Comment: @o_oTurtle Indeed clang makes this optimization.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, check out the related link at the bottom. The guy in question wants to make this optimization mandatory and I support his case 100%.